# Accessing Docker Vault secrets using Spring Cloud Starter Vault Config Could Not Resolve

Tags: docker, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

I am running a `Docker Vault container` in `dev` mode, and I can't read a secret located at `/secret/mobsters/` called `password`.

Here are [Spring logs](https://pastebin.com/PUccyEan).

Running `vault kv get secret/mobsters` returns the password key value pair. I can also access the vault server locally.

Here is how I am referencing the secret:

```
@Value("${password}")
String password;

@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() {
    System.out.println("My password is: " + password);
}
```

The `Spring Cloud Vault` configuration is setup using a `bootstrap.yml` file:

```
spring.application.name: mobsters
spring.cloud.vault:
host: localhost
port: 8200
scheme: http
authentication: TOKEN
token: ...
```

I am getting an exception with the message (full exception [here](https://pastebin.com/PUccyEan)):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'password' in value "${password}"`
```

From Vault UI:

[image]

Comment: Looks like as if you were using Vault 0.10.0. If so, see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/209.

Comment: I downgraded the docker container to v0.9.5 and it worked! You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Spring Vault/Spring Cloud Vault with HashiCorp Vault 0.10.0 does not work as the key/value backend is mounted with versioning enabled by default. This has some significance as the versioned API has changed entirely and breaks existing client implementations. Context paths and response structure are different.

You have two options:

1. Use an older Vault version (such as 0.9.5)
2. Try to cope with API changes until Spring Cloud Vault finds an approach to use the new API. You need to:

   - Set `spring.cloud.vault.generic.backend=secret/data` in your bootstrap configuration.
   - Prefix property names with `data.` so `@Value("${hello.world}")` becomes `@Value("${data.hello.world}")`.

Comment: In my case, I set spring.cloud.config.server.vault.backend=secret/data and prefaced my property names with "data." -- works! Looks like I have Vault v1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a way to fix this.

In your `bootstrap.yml`, make sure that `generic.enabled` is false and `kv.enabled` is true.

```
spring:
  ...
  cloud.vault:
      ...
      kv.enabled: true
      generic.enabled: false
```

According to [this answer on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/224#issuecomment-402375727):

> The main difference between those two is that kv injects the data
>   segment in the context path and unwraps nested data responses.
>
> If you're running a [springboot] version before 2.0, then you need to implement an
>   org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfigurer bean that is
>   exposed to the bootstrap context. SecretBackendConfigurer accepts a
>   path and a PropertyTransformer that transforms properties before
>   exposing these as PropertySource.